# Position road label below road in CartoCSS

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

I would like to force road label to be on south side (below) east-west roads.
After implementing text-dy: -20, the results are not consistent.
Is there an another setting I could use to force this label placement on roads?

```
#roadlabel::labels{
text-avoid-edges:true;    
text-allow-overlap:false;     
text-character-spacing:0.5;    
text-transform:uppercase;    
text-size: 24;
text-name: [FULLNAME];
text-face-name: 'Helvetica Neue LT Std 75 Bold';
text-fill: #fff;
text-halo-fill: fadeout(black, 40%);
text-halo-radius: 1;
text-placement: line;          
text-dy: -20;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is: `shield` CartoCSS related properties. As explained [here](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/cartocss/properties/#shield), "(i)f you are displaying road shields on a map (for example, highway markers), these CartoCSS properties define the shield styling." So instead of using `text-dy`, you have to use `shield-dy`.